# How to know wifi card model on laptop?

Tags: wireless, hardware

I want know model and characteristics of my wifi card. How to do it in ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo lspci`  (with https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en for troubleshooting info)